# Change BPM value of Spotify Song

Tags: ios, spotify, audio-player, beatsmusic

I'm trying to build an application that plays Spotify songs. I'm really confused about how to change the BPM (beats per minute) value of Spotify songs.

**First Step:** Login through Spotify.

**Second Step:** Get current user all album.

**Third Step**: Get album track.

**Last Step:** Play track.

I have done all steps with Spotify delegates. but I want to change the BPM value of the track. This is possible because some applications change the BPM of Spotify songs.

Can someone please explain to me how to change the BPM value?

Comment: This isn't possible anymore, because Spotify discontinued streaming inside third-party apps. Also, the apps you saw, don't work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You simply can't. Unless you have the open source to the song, you can try changing it to fit your BPM. If you wanted to do this, you'd have to find something similar to a software that can change tempo, like Audacity. Not sure if it has an API though.

Comment: You can change the *metadata* of the song, to record what the BPM of that song is likely to be. Have you verified that perhaps the OP is talking about that possibility?